# Is other-regardingness a word?

Tags: synonyms

I'm writing an essay and am wondering whether the following sentence is correct: "I investigate the tension between self-interest and other-regardingness."

Is other-regardingness a word? On the one hand it's in [the Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/other-regardingness). On the other Chrome gives me an error, and when I search Google for "define other-regardingness" the only dictionary definition that comes up is Oxford's.

(And if it exists, are there any synonyms, just in case some people aren't familiar with it?)

Comment: It seems correct in that its wordness is corroborated, but that doesn't mean that someone can't knock a mark off for style. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=altruism%2Cother-regardingness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caltruism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cother%20-%20regardingness%3B%2Cc0) (altruism,other-regardingness) could be used to justify a judgement of lack of idiomaticity.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, thanks for introducing me to Google Ngrams!

Comment: They're useful, but must be used with care, as, for example, that,that will pick up things like 'Give me that! That was very naughty!'

Comment: "Thoughtful", "considerate", and "kind" are near synonyms that are less academic jargon and more natural language. "Considerate," in particular, refers to considering others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a word. *Oxford* is about as reliable as you can get. I agree with Edwin that people may knock it for its awkwardness. For what it is worth, I looked up the word in the *[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com)* (OED) and it has

> other-regardingness
>
> *n.* regard for others; altruism.
>
> 1894   *United Presb. Mag.* 11 310   That all morality is summed up in altruism—other-regardingness or love.
>
> 1958   *Times Lit. Suppl.* 31 Jan. 54/5   Reason, objectivity, tolerance, charity, other-regardingness—these are not natural gifts of men.
>
> 1992   *Amer. Jrnl. Polit. Sci.* 36 753   That degree of other-regardingness that would come to be called ‘self-interest properly understood’.

That it has been used  felicitously as late as 1992, in *[American Journal of Political Science](https://ajps.org/)*, shows that it is alive. However, a [One Look Dictionary search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=other-regardingness&ls=a) did not even return the *Oxford* use that you found.